# How to override native isArray method is nesessary?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to override native `isArray` method like the following:

```
function isArray (obj) {
    isArray = Array.isArray || function(obj) {
        return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) == '[object Array]';
    };

    return isArray(obj);
}

var ok = isArray([]);
```

But unfortunately `isArray` always return function. What's wrong?

Comment: Because it would be unusual for `Array.isArray` to be missing?

Comment: You are using the same name for the function and the variable... Why do you need the function at all?

Comment: Which browser are you trying with?

Comment: @DaveNewton In IE < 9, it sure is

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/bj28px3y/2/show/ (tested in Chrome 38 and IE 8)

Comment: @Ian Turns out that's the definition of "unusual".

Comment: @DaveNewton That's actually the definition of "(unfortunately) happens more often than you think and shouldn't be ignored"

Comment: @Ian Actually, flagger, it doesn't happen more than I think, because browser statistics. I have zero issues ignoring obsolete browsers, and on the rare occasions somebody makes me have an issue, polyfills. Lighten up.

Comment: @DaveNewton You were flagged because your comment was rude, when you could've had a normal conversation (or said something helpful). Browser statistics mean (almost) nothing for this, because as long as the stats aren't 0% use, it's relevant. **You** may not **need** to support IE<9, but why should that apply to everyone else? And as you've pointed out, which I agree with, a polyfill is the solution (which **is what the OP has**), and it never hurts to include. So instead of trolling the OP, try being helpful, you're just bloating the comments

Comment: @Ian The irony is strong in this one. Re-lighten up. Also note that my comment *does* answer the "why": it *is* unusual, because the vast majority of people don't use a browser that doesn't have it natively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is how you should implement

```
if (!Array.isArray) {
  Array.isArray = function(arg) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(arg) === '[object Array]';
  };
}
```

and this is how you should call

```
var ok = Array.isArray([]);
```

[read the manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)